# Not able to navigate between two templates in a Django application

Tags: python, django, templates, view, navigation

I have a ran into a difficulty when navigating between different templates in a Django (v3.2) application. The app is called 'manage_remittance'.
The default landing page (which uses template *manage_remittance/templates/manage_remittance/view_remittance.html*) for the app should show a list of items (list is not relevant at the moment), and at the top of that list there should be a link, leading to another page in the same app, which would allow to add new items to the list.

The form that is invoked first is here:
manage_remittance/templates/manage_remittance/view_remittance.html

```
{% extends "root.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% url 'manage_remittance:remittance_add' as remittance_add %}

{% block title %}
VIEW REMITTANCES PAGE
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="list-group col-6">
<a href="{{ remittance_add }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action shadow-mt list-group-flush list-group-item-dark text-light">Click here to add remittance data</a>
</div>
```

I want to be able to get to another template (*manage_remittance/templates/manage_remittance/remittance_add.html*), but the `{{ remittance_add }}` has no value.

In addition, when I specify exact name of the html file (remittance_add.html) in the a href (see above), and click on it, I get a following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in sanctions_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    [name='login']
    login/ [name='login']
    logout/ [name='logout']
    manage_remittance/ [name='view_remittance']
    manage_remittance/ remittance_add/ [name='create_remittance']
    ^static/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, manage_remittance/remittance_add.html, didn’t match any of these.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

fragment of urls.py for the project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', login_view, name='login'),
    path('login/', login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('manage_remittance/', include('manage_remittance.urls')),      # namespace='manage_remittance'
 ]
```

urls.py at manage_remittance app:

```
from .views import (
    CreateRemittanceInfo,
    RemittanceListView
)

app_name = 'manage_remittance'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', RemittanceListView.as_view(), name='view_remittance'),
    path('remittance_add/', CreateRemittanceInfo.as_view(), name='create_remittance'),
    ]
```

views.py at manage_remittance app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .models import Remittance

class CreateRemittanceInfo(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Remittance
    fields = ['remittance_text']
    template_name_suffix = '_add'

class RemittanceListView(ListView):
    model = Remittance
    template_name = 'manage_remittance/view_remittance.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an issue in your urls:

```
manage_remittance/ remittance_add/ [name='create_remittance']
```

the `name` does not match with

```
manage_remittance:remittance_add
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right about this one, but there is something else wrong, as I still was getting an empty value for remittance_add.

Comment: It seems quite simple: in your template, you should display a list, which is not the case. Have a look at Django User Guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

It should look like  
```
{% for object in object_list %}
<p>{{object.remittance_text}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It seems quite simple: in your template, you should display a list, which is not the case. Have a look at Django User Guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

It should look like  
```
{% for object in object_list %}
<p>{{object.remittance_text}}</p>
{% endfor %}
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite simple: in your template, you should display a list, which is not the case. Have a look at Django User Guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

It should look like

```
{% for object in object_list %}
<p>{{object.remittance_text}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```